# Test class for MetaDataAPI which adds new values to picklist fields

Tags: apex, api, metadata-api

I have used metadata APIs to create new values to picklist values using apex.
But unfortunately, I am not able to understand how to write the test class for the same.

Can someone help me

This is my code

```
@future(callout=true)
    public static void addNewPiklistValue(String value) {
        Refined_MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new Refined_MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.timeout_x =120000;
        service.SessionHeader = new Refined_MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        Refined_MetadataService.CustomField customFieldOfPO = 
            (Refined_MetadataService.CustomField) service.readMetadata('CustomField', new String[] { 
                'SBQQ__ProductOption__c.Target__c' }).getRecords()[0];    
        Refined_MetadataService.CustomValue valueToAdd = new Refined_MetadataService.CustomValue();
        valueToAdd.fullName = value;
        valueToAdd.default_x=false;
        customFieldOfLead.valueSet.valueSetDefinition.value.add(valueToAdd);
        Refined_MetadataService.SaveResult result = service.updateMetadata(new Refined_MetadataService.Metadata[] 
                                                                   {customFieldOfPO})[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web service calls such as this [can be mocked](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm) so your test case could look something like this:

```
@IsTest
private class MetadataServiceTest {

    private class MetadataServiceMock implements WebServiceMock {

        Integer callCount = 0;

        public void doInvoke(
            Object stub,
            Object request,
            Map<String, Object> response,
            String endpoint,
            String soapAction,
            String requestName,
            String responseNS,
            String responseName,
            String responseType
        ) {
            // Basic mocking only
            if (request instanceOf MetadataService.deleteMetadata_element) {
                callCount++;
                MetadataService.deleteMetadataResponse_element res =
                    new MetadataService.deleteMetadataResponse_element();
                res.result = new MetadataService.DeleteResult[] {};
                response.put('response_x', res);
            } else {
                System.assert(false, 'unexpected request ' + request);
            }
        }
    }

    @IsTest
    static void delete_ok() {

        MetadataServiceMock mock = new MetadataServiceMock();
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, mock);

        Template2__mdt template = queryTemplate();

        String message = TemplatesTabController.deleteTemplate(template.Id);
        System.assertEquals(null, message);

        // Delete done
        System.assertEquals(1, mock.callCount);
    }

    ...
}
```

This code relates to a custom metadata type not picklist metadata but your pattern will be similar with different types used.